# wget failing when I enter variable name in command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a small bash script to download a file from my webserver. I pass the $File variable through the command line and then insert it into the wget command as follows:

```
File=${1}

wget -a /home/wgetlog.txt -nH -nd --accept=txt "http://192.168.1.21/files/$File/$File.txt"
```

If I run the command ./download.sh media - It gives the following in the log file:

```
--2014-04-07 17:44:36--  http://192.168.1.21/files//.txt
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
```

Is it due to me passing the variable side by side? Is the syntax correct? Or is there a better way of doing this :)

Comment: Your parameter is clearly not passed to your script. Are you sure you don't have an extra space between the script name and the parameter ??

Comment: Try running the script using `set -x` to see the variable assignments.

Comment: Your code is valid, so you're more than likely calling the script incorrect, perhaps with an extra space as @krisFR mentioned

Comment: I think this belongs in StackOverflow

Comment: What are you using for your interpreter? (First line). /bin/sh, /bin/bash, /bin/csh?

Comment: An extra space alone wouldn't cause any problems. It would have to be quoted or escaped, creating an extra argument.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson My bad, you are right, an extra space alone wouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: hi all, the command I am passing is: ./download.sh media with one space, spaces do not seem to make a difference

Comment: Either `File` is being unset, or you've misspelled the variable name somewhere, or you aren't running the code you think you're running (an old version, perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

When writing a script that takes command line arguments, you should really check the parameters given.

For example:

```
File=${1}
if [[ -z $File ]]
then
  echo "ERROR: file name required"
  exit
fi

echo wget -a /home/wgetlog.txt -nH -nd --accept=txt "http://192.168.1.21/files/$File/$File.txt"
```

I'm guessing here, but if your script is called "doit.sh" and you are invoking it as:

```
doit.sh $File
```

and $File is not defined in your command line shell, then it will pass no parameters to your script and hence your script will fail in the way you describe.

You need to invoke it with a real file name. E.g.

```
doit.sh fred
```